# How to disable dates in Datepicker using dates entered into database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo, datepicker

What I want to achieve is to block out dates in the Jquery Datepicker that have already been booked. So far I have managed to build a working form with a functioning Datepicker that uses $_POST to send data to my database. I know that I should be using the BeforeShowDay Jquery function but I can't quite figure out how to implement it. Let me walk you through my code.

```
<?php require_once('inc/header.php');
```

Connect to the database using PDO and use prepare to input the data. All working fine.

```
require('database.php');

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO besucher (name, surname, email, guests, fromDate, toDate, questions) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam('1', $_POST['Name']);
$stmt->bindParam('2', $_POST['LastName']);
$stmt->bindParam('3', $_POST['Email']);
$stmt->bindParam('4', $_POST['Guests']);
$stmt->bindParam('5', $_POST['From']);
$stmt->bindParam('6', $_POST['To']);
$stmt->bindParam('7', $_POST['Questions']);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is where I retrieve the info from the database.

```
    try {
        $results = query("SELECT fromDate, toDate FROM besucher");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
        exit;
    }

?>
```

The form itself.

```
<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Make a booking enquiry</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--endrow-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form role="form action="form.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="LastName">Surname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Enter Surname" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Guests">Number of Guests</label>
          <input type="number" id="Guests" class="form-control" name="Guests" placeholder="z.b. 4" required>
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="From">From <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label>
          <input type="text" id="From" name="From" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">     
          <label for="To">To <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label>
          <input type="text" id="To" name="To" class="form-control" required>      
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="textarea">Questions?</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="Questions" rows="3"></textarea>             
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="checkbox" class="sr-only">Checkbox</label>
          <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> I would like to recieve emails from Muscheltraum              
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>     
    </div>
  </div><!--endrow-->
</div><!--container-->
</div><!--wrap-->

<?php require_once('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

This is the datepicker.js file code where I want to put the BeforeShowDay function. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the fromDate and toDate from my SELECT query into my date-picker and how that would fit into the below code. It's really frustrating because I know exactly what I want to do and how the pieces should fit together but I just can't work how to implement it.

From the Jquery UI API

```
beforeShowDayType: Function( Date date )

Default: null
A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.




    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "de" ] );

    $(function() {
      $( "#From" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        minDate:0,
        maxDate: "+1y", 
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#To" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
      });
      $( "#To" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        maxDate: "+1y",
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#From" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea, didn't test but it should work.

**PHP**

Let's assume you have your dates to disable in an array in PHP

```
$disablethese = array("2014-01-03","2014-01-13","2014-01-23");
```

Print your `From Date` field with disabled dates in `data` attribute using `json_encode`

```
<input type="text" id="From" name="From" class="form-control" required data-disablethese="<?=json_encode($disablethese)?>">
```

**JQuery**

```
var disablethese = $("#From").data("disablethese"); //this will auto-decode JSON to Array
```

Now you can use `disablethese` variable in your `beforeShowDate`

```
var disablethese = ["2014-01-03","2014-01-13","2014-01-23"];

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ disablethese.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/wnTxv/)

Comment: I tried your solution turning the date into an array like this.

`try {
        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT fromDate, toDate FROM besucher");
        $sth->execute();

        $disablethese = $sth->fetchAll();
        print_r($disablethese);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
        
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
        exit;
        
        }`
It disables all dates in my From datepicker. In my Jquery function I added the following code 
`beforeShowDay: function(disablethese) {
                return [false, "highlighted", "booked out"];
        }`

Comment: I don't think your `beforeShowDay` usage is correct. I edited my answer, check the usage, I also put JSFiddle example. Also your PHP must return exact same format of array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
include'db.php';
$Pro_id = 4;
$dateslistselect1[]='';
$queryres = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT start_date,end_date FROM table_name WHERE id='".$Pro_id."' AND YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) OR YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryres))
{
$start = strtotime($row['start_date']);
$end = strtotime($row['end_date']);            
for ($i1=$start; $i1<=$end; $i1+=86400) { 
$dateslistselect1[]= '"'.date('d-m-Y',$i1).'"';   
}          
}
$dateslistselect1=array_filter($dateslistselect1);
$totaldayslist1 =implode(", ", $dateslistselect1);   
?>
<script>
var disableddates = [<?php echo $totaldayslist1; ?>];     
function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
var disableddates = [];     
$("#in").datepicker({
minDate: new Date(),
dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onSelect: function (selected) {
var dt = new Date(selected);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
$("#out").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
}
});
$("#out").datepicker({
minDate: new Date(),
dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onSelect: function (selected) {
var dt = new Date(selected);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate());
$("#out").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
}
});
/* $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", dt );*/
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.